# Javascript unhex for mysql

Tags: javascript, node.js, bookshelf.js

I want to to save binary length 16 uuid in MySQL:

In MySQL I just have to do this:

```
unhex(replace(uuid(), '-', '')
```

I have done this:

```
var uuid = require('node-uuid');
var id = new Buffer(uuid.v4().replace(/-/g, ''), 'binary');
```

I got a Buffer[32] value inserted into the database. That is not right, it is not fully save in binary.

I am using booshelfjs orm for database command, so I am not planning to run MySQL command on my code.

Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UUID generated is represented in hexadecimal. Accordingly, it is necessary to use not binary input encoding, but hexadecimal:

```
var uuid = require('node-uuid');
var id = new Buffer(uuid.v4().replace(/-/g, ''), 'hex');
```

Comment: value 6d06794f8e194bc09e5eb3ab78d779e9 is save as hex(id) => B7F134C3756C469297D4E396DD44C749

Comment: Show console output for this code: 
`var u = '6d06794f8e194bc09e5eb3ab78d779e9';
var id = new Buffer(u, 'hex');
console.log(u, id.toString('hex'));`

Answer (score 0):

In vanilla JS, supports both node and browser:

```
  function unhex(s) {
    var arr = []
    for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i += 2) {
      var c = s.substr(i, 2);
      arr.push(parseInt(c, 16));
    }
    return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, arr);
  }
```